# A criterion to determine if a matrix is invertible by its norm

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

I'm trying to prove an exercise, but I have no clue to start, any tip?

This is the exercise:

Suppose that a linear application $A:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb R^n $ satisfy $\parallel A-Id\parallel <1$, then $A$ is invertible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this proves that $ker(A) = \{0\}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: I assume you use $\|A\|= sup_{\|x\|=1}\|A(x)\|$. Suppose $A$ is not invertible. There exists $x$ such that $\|x\|=1$ and $A(x)=0$. $\|(A-Id)(x)\| =\|x\|=1$.